# Python Syntax Error but looks fine to me. Help?

Tags: python, syntax-error

Right now I'm working on a Tetris Game (sorta, I found a Tetris example for Python on a website, I've been copying it but adding some of my own stuff), and just finished writing all the code but have had a couple syntax errors. I've been able to fix all of them but this last syntax error is confusing to me.

```
    def pieceDropped(self):
        for i in range(4):
            x = self.curX + self.curPiece.x(i)
            y = self.curY - self.curPiece.y(i)
            self.setShapeAt(x, y, self.curPiece.shape()

        self.removeFullLines()
```

The specific syntax error is on the last line of the function and I don't understand why, the indentation and whitespace all seems correct. So could someone explain how this is a syntax error?

Comment: Remember to pick an answer. ^_-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't close the parenthesis of `self.setShapeAt`.

Comment: Happens to me all the time. It's confusing at first that the exception occurs on the line *after* the actual error, but that's understandable since unclosed parentheses implicitly serve as line continuators.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra whitespace on the last line - just ahead `self.removeFullLines()`. Its indenting is thus not the same as the `for` line's indenting. EDIT: Seems to be corrected now.

Always use the same indent sequence - choose either tabs, or n whitespaces. But be consistent. Some editors (such as VIM) are able to insert the appropriate number of whitespaces whenever you hit tab.